# minStack subclass using one object for min stack and regular stack

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, data-structures, polymorphism

I'm working through the CTCI book and found this answer confusing.  The goal is to create a stack data structure that can push, pop, and min (get minimum element in the stack) in O(1).  I coded up a class that has two stacks, one to hold the minimums and one that works as a regular stack.  The code is below.  This works to the best of my knowledge from testing.

```
   public static class StackWithMin extends Stack<Integer>{
      Stack<Integer> stack;
      Stack<Integer> minStack;

      public StackWithMin(){
         stack = new Stack<Integer>();
         minStack = new Stack<Integer>();
      }

      public void push(int value){
         if(value <= min()){
            minStack.push(value); 
         }
         stack.push(value);
      }

      public Integer pop(){
         int value = stack.pop();
         if(value == min()){
            minStack.pop();
         }
         return value;
      }
      public int min(){
         if(minStack.isEmpty()){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
         }
         return minStack.peek();  
      }
   }
```

However, the answer given in the book is not completely clear to me.  I have taken two courses in Java but spent the last two in C so my OOP concepts are a bit rusty.  The class has only one stack field in it and uses the super call to update the 'regular' stack and the s2 call to update the min stack.  Looking at this in Java visualizer shows only one stack object that is apparently storing two different stacks.  This implementation works but I'm not sure exactly why.  Clarification would be appreciated!

```
public class Q2 /* MinStack */ extends Stack<Integer> {
    private Stack<Integer> min = new Stack<Integer>();

    public void push(int item) {
        if (min.isEmpty() || item < min()) {
            min.push(item);
        }
        super.push(item);
    }

    public Integer pop() {
        int item = super.pop();
        if (item == min()) {
            min.pop();
        }
        return item;
    }

    public Integer min() {
        return min.peek();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code indeed generating two stacks. The fact that `Q2` class extends `Stack<Integer>` class means that everything exists in the parent class exists in the `Q2` class too, including the "regular" stack, but just to access it in Java you need to use the `super` keyword.

This image can explain this OOP concept of including the parent class (everything that exists in "Bird" exists in "AngryBird"):

[image]

Now since your `Q2` class "including" a stack and functioning like a stack, you are creating a new, second, stack for the minimum value as a member in your class.

If you are wondering what is "wrong" in your solution, is that you are actually not using the base class, your code would work even without the `extends Stack<Integer>` statement.